# Issue on Passing Instance of a Class in other Class Constructor

Tags: c#

I am having issue on passing/ connecting one class `Director()` in the constructor of another class `Movie()`. Basically what I want to do is to have two different domain for `Movie` and `Director` but use instance of `Director` in constructor of the `Movie` class. I have a declaration of  `public Director director;` in the movie class but how I can pass it as constructor parameter in Movie?

```
void Main()
{
    Director d1 = new Director("Wachowski Brothers", "USA"); 
    Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", d1.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(m1.Title);
}

class Movie
{
    public Director director; 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Movie( string title, Director directorName ){
     Title = title;

    }
}
class Director
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }

    public Director(string name, string nationality){
        Name = name;
        Nationality = nationality;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
void Main()
{
    Director d1 = new Director("Wachowski Brothers", "USA"); 
    Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", d1);
    Console.WriteLine(m1.Title);
    Console.WriteLine(m1.director.Name);
}

class Movie
{
    public Director director; 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Movie( string title, Director directorName ){
     Title = title;
     director=directorName;

    }
}
class Director
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }

    public Director(string name, string nationality){
        Name = name;
        Nationality = nationality;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answers the question, you should consider adding some explanatory text that describes what was wrong with the OP's code.  This would be beneficial to other users.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to pass the `Name`, but the whole instance. So instead of

```
Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", d1.Name);
```

you mean

```
Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", d1);
```

Comment: Thanks Rene but how I can access the value of the `d1`? I mean in case of getting the nationality of director or even setting it ? How I can do it in main?

Comment: I don't really understand that question? You do have `d1` in scope in `Main`, so you can either `d1.Nationality = ...` or via the movie `m1.director.Nationality = ...`.

Comment: Ok when I try `Console.WriteLine(m1.director.Nationality);`  I am getting this error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @MonaCoder Oh yes, because in your `Movie` constructor you did not set the `director` field to the passed `directorName` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", d1.Name);
```

should be

```
Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", d1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create director in same time movie like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Movie m1 = new Movie("Matrix", "Wachowski Brothers", "USA");
    Console.WriteLine(m1.Title);
    Console.WriteLine(m1.director.Name);
}

class Movie
{
    public Director director; 
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Movie( string title, Director director ){
     Title = title;
     this.director=director;

    }

    public Movie( string title, string DirectorName, string DirectorNationality){
     Title = title;
     director=new Director(DirectorName, DirectorNationality);

    }
}


class Director
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }

    public Director(string name, string nationality){
        Name = name;
        Nationality = nationality;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the above posts suggest.  Your function signature.

```
public Movie( string title, Director directorName )
```

calls for an object of type Director.  You are passing in only the name, 
which is a String.  Naming is important here.  You are calling Director "directorName".  That's where you're getting confused.